# How to get the tags associated to an article in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, tags, joomla3.1

I need to get the TAGS associated with an article in Joomla 3.1.5

I have tried the following but they do not return a string:

```
echo $article->item->tags->itemTags;
```

and

```
$tags = $article->get("tags");
```

And just for the record I am loading the article info as such (getting the article title works perfectly)

```
$article = JTable::getInstance("content");
$article->load(JRequest::getInt("id"));
$pageTitle = $article->get("title");
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look in `components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php`, the tags are being displayed like so:

```
if ($this->params->get('show_tags', 1) && !empty($this->item->tags->itemTags)) {
    $this->item->tagLayout = new JLayoutFile('joomla.content.tags');
    echo $this->item->tagLayout->render($this->item->tags->itemTags);
}
```

So you can base it on this:

Hope it helps

Answer (score 16):

If you want to load article tags in a module/plugin etc, and assuming `$id` is the id of the article, you can do

```
$tags = new JHelperTags;
$tags->getItemTags('com_content.article', $id);
var_dump($tags);
```

Answer (score 3):

Rendering article tags in a module that displays Joomla articles, such as mod_articles_latest.

```
$itemtags = (new JHelperTags)->getItemTags('com_content.article', $item->id);
$taglayout = new JLayoutFile('joomla.content.tags');
$tags='';
if( !empty($itemtags) )
    $tags = '<div class="itemtags">'.str_replace(',','',$taglayout->render($itemtags)).'</div>';
```

Comment: Hi, I've tryed this suggestion in my mod_articles_latest override without success. No tags are displayed. Can you help me?

Comment: Did you print the $tags constant in default.php eg: `<?php echo $tags; ?>`

Comment: What a shame!!! I forgot it!!! :( Thanks so much Nadal for your suggestion. I would like also to display into a different way those tags. The actual html structure for rendering tags is as "ul" and "li". Where should I work to edit this structure with an override? Could you please suggest me?

Comment: Ok, I can override /layouts/joomla/content/tags.php but this way I'll overryde also the layout for articles meanwhile I would have a specific layout only for the module. Any suggestion about this?

Comment: If you remove the list element, you'll lose the tag's numerical value used for the class. What is the desired output? You can achieve any display by manipulating CSS, without removing the `<li>`.

If you must remove the list element, use preg_replace instead of str_replace and write the regex format to strip all but the anchor. Test your expression format at [link](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to Marko D's answer, add this to format the tags like in an article/blog layout.

```
echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.tags', $tags->itemTags);
```