# Rendering article tags in mod_articles_latest

Tags: php, joomla

I'm trying to create an override for my Latest Article Module to show tags for every article according to this stack: [Rendering article tags in a module that displays Joomla articles, such as mod_articles_latest.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48391017/5197217)

I've tryed to implement the lines of code suggested but in my case I don't see any tag displayed in the output. Why? What am I missing?

I've done a simple override of the mod_latest_articles and inserted those lines of code into a div.

Comment: Because your question is directly Joomla-related (and because you already have a JSX account), you might like to post your question on Joomla Stack Exchange to reach a more dedicated audience.

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot to echo the $tags... :)